# consistent formattedValue of currency in backoffice and spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We're having some difficulty with the provided formattedValue of the Product's Price.

Having USD, for example as the active currency.
The Product's formattedValue is of this format: `US$421.08`
How do we catch this exact format in frontend?

Is there an available spartacus method that translates a value with the assigned format?

Angular's currency pipe doesn't do the trick either.
I only managed to display it as `$421.08`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom pipe https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes and handle the logic on what you want it to be displayed.

For example, pass in the formatted value and the current currency iso string taken from `currency.service - getActive()` to concat both to display US$421.08, or any other mutation.